# Find XML entry number

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I need to get the node number of an entry but I only have the LOG_ID. How find that number out?

```
<LOG>
<ENTRY LOG_ID="01042012"/>
<ENTRY LOG_ID="03052012"/>
<ENTRY LOG_ID="09052012"/>
</LOG>
```

Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use E4X processing as described [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html) and the [getting started documentation](http://wso2.org/project/mashup/0.2/docs/e4xquickstart.html):

```
var myXML:XML = 
 <LOG>
  <ENTRY LOG_ID="01042012"/>
  <ENTRY LOG_ID="03052012"/>
  <ENTRY LOG_ID="09052012"/>
 </LOG>

trace( myXML.ENTRY.(@LOG_ID==09052012).childIndex() ); /* retrieve entire node */
```

You can also store a reference to this node in an `XML` object:

```
 var index:int = myXML.ENTRY.(@LOG_ID==09052012).childIndex();
```

Note: The `childindex` function (and a few others) work on individual nodes. However, if your input example has multiple nodes with the same attribute value you're using to retrieve you will get a list of nodes (i.e. an `XMLList`) instead of a single node. Now, in order to find out the indices of such children you will need to do the following:

```
for each ( var selectedNode in myXML.ENTRY.(@LOG_ID==09052012) )
    trace( selectedNode.childIndex() );
```

You can always check if your E4X query returned a list via the following:

```
var candidates:XMLList = myXML.ENTRY.(@LOG_ID==09052012) as XMLList;
if (candidates != null) { // a list 
        // do something ...
}
```

Comment: If I run the code **trace** is empty. I guess a number should come up?

Comment: @Uli: I had put `entry` instead of `ENTRY`. Can you try with my updated answer? Make sure that whatever you put in E4X after the `myXML` variable name matches in case the actual entry/entries in your XML file. Also note that E4X typically skips the root node (i.e. `LOG` in your case).

Comment: This comes up: `Error #1086: The childIndex method only works on lists containing one item.`

Comment: @Uli: So, your E4X query returns an `XMLList` instead of a single node which is what `childindex` works on. Can you try changing the `LOG_ID` to such that there is only an unique instance found? Otherwise, you will have to save the query result in an `XMLList` and iterate over each element and call `childindex` on these.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Can you show me an example please?